# Highchart Set Values to zone from another column

Tags: php, postgresql, highcharts

In my table i have 3 columns

```
|week | % |pts |
|:----|:--|:---|
|  1  |34 |37  |
|  2  |44 |21  |
|  3  |41 |67  |
|  4  |59 |135 |
|  5  |49 |102 |
|  6  |57 |11  |
|  7  |60 |4   |
|  8  |47 |53  |
```

The first column is using for the x-axis
The second column (percentage numbers) i use to visualise in a spline
In the third column are the Points (which i generate in a query to set the percentage of the second column).
What i want is to change the color of the Promoter (%) spline if the promoter points is < 43 pts. without to show the spline of Promoter Points. It is very tricky, do you have an idea?

Here the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/czmnra04/

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to pass the column points in which you want the zone value https://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/jkteaz1m/3/

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you want to achieve. Because zones are used to set intervals for which given points are to have different colors. If for a given point, e.g. the first one with value 34, you want to set a specific color, then you shouldn't use zones for that. It will be easier to help if you explain the problem more clearly, maybe visualizing it in the form of an image or screenshot will be helpful.

Comment: @RohanKumar, Hello, i am sorry that i was not clear. What i want is to change the color of the Promoter (%) spline if the promoter points is < 43 pts. without to show the spline of Promoter Points. It is very tricky, do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to condition the color based on the data in the 3rd column then using zones won't work here because they are based on the axis and the axis is generated from the values in your 2nd column.

So if you want to change the color based on the custom value from column 3 for specific points from column 2, you can use the `chart.events.load()` callback function with logic that conditionally updates the colors of all points using `point.update()` method.

```js
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function() {
      const chart = this;

      chart.series.forEach(series => {
        series.data.forEach(point => {
          if (point.pts < 43) {
            point.update({
              color: 'red'
            })
          }
        })
      })
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ydc3m45n/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load 
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update